Не работает подключение к ip камере через Onvif c#
При подключении к ip камере с services все нормально.
Но GetProfiles не получает никаких профилей от камеры.
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            deviceUri = new UriBuilder("http://onvif/device_service");

            string[] addr = address.Text.Split(':');
            deviceUri.Host = addr[0];
            if (addr.Length == 2)
            {
                deviceUri.Port = int.Parse(addr[1]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("IP: " + deviceUri);

            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding;
            HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            httpTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
            binding = new CustomBinding(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8), httpTransport);

            Device.DeviceClient device = new Device.DeviceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(deviceUri.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine("Device: " + device.Endpoint.Address);

            Device.Service[] services = device.GetServices(false); // false - Include only needed services. true - Include all services for the device.
            Console.WriteLine("Services: ");

                Device.Service xmedia = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Namespace == "http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl");
                if (xmedia != null)
                {
                    media = new Media.Media2Client(binding, new EndpointAddress(deviceUri.ToString()));
                    media.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = login.Text;
                    media.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = passwordBox.Password;
                    media.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

                    Media.MediaProfile[] profiles = media.GetProfiles(null, null);
                    if (profiles != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var p in profiles)
                        {
                            listBox.Items.Add(p.Name);
                        }
                    }
          }



Код выглядит нормально. Больше кроме "не работает", ничего не понятно.

Получается что в этом коде в переменную profiles ничего не поступает. У меня не отрабатывает условие if, то есть в profiles ничего нет, а должны подгружаться профили из камеры.

@aepot Может быть нужно как-то включить сам Onvif на камере?

Чтобы дополнить вопрос, его можно отредактировать.

@aepot Добавил полностью функцию с которой возникают проблемы, есть ли какие-то догадки, почему я не могу получить профили от ip камеры?


"http:/onvif/device_service" опечатка в адресе, должно быть "http://onvif/device_service" 2) deviceUri.Port = Convert.ToInt16(addr[1]); - там int, то есть ToInt32 должно быть. А ещё лучше int.Parse(...) вместо конверта.


@aepot При изменении адреса с двумя слешами появляется ошибка, скрин который прикрепил к вопросу. С ссылкой же с одним слешом, сервисы не могу получить.

значит камера не поддерживает http или оно на другом порту

@eri Тогда бы я не смог подключиться к камере через браузер, а я это могу сделать.

Это уже проблема не кода, вероятно, а сетевая или инфраструктурная. Тексты в вопрос надо вставлять текстом, кстати текст исключения переведён немного криво, по типу гуглотранслейта. Суть исключения "не могу подключиться", больше оно ничего не означает.

Проблема заключалась в том, что на самой камере версия библиотеки Onvif была устаревшая. При подключении к другой ip камере все происходит нормально и программа работает.
